# Is it possible to change the screen display names in MacOS for a multi monitor setup

Tags: display, catalina, system-settings

I have a 15" MacBook Pro (with Catalina 10.15.1) with a multi monitor setup using USB-C adapters:

[image: multi monitor setup]

I've using this setup since Maverick, as you can see in the next screenshot, the 3 screens have the same name **C24F390** just with a (n) number appended:
[image: 3 screens with the same name C24F390 and a number appended]

Which causes confusion every time the video adapters are connected and disconnected, since the order (and therefore the numbers) change.

Is there a way to change the screen display names in System Preferences or maybe with a third party App? It will be very useful to send a windows to a specific screen but as the names are just the same it is a little uncomfortable (I will like to rename the 3 screens: L, C & R, which stands for Left, Center & Right screen).

The order is not a problem itself, but the screen names are, because sometimes I disconnect an adapter to work on specific tasks and I just want fewer screens.

If you need more information, just let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very clearly setup. I have the same issue, and I can't believe my Catalina OSX Also can't recognize the individual monitors and displace them on every monitor switch. It should be easy to change names... but not. Hoping for a solution.

Answer (score 11):

SwitchResX will let you rename your monitors. You can download a free 10 day trial of it to do so.

To address your root problem though, try the free terminal tool I wrote, [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer), that lets describe your monitor layout as a terminal command. I then use BetterTouchTool to execute these profiles via hotkeys. I have the same issue as you, when I plug in my monitors the layout randomly changes.

For example, on my 4 monitor setup at home I have this profile: `displayplacer "id:A46D2F5E-487B-CC69-C588-ECFD519016E5 res:3840x2160 hz:60 color_depth:8 scaling:off origin:(0,0) degree:0" "id:F466F621-B5FA-04A0-0800-CFA6C258DECD res:1440x900 color_depth:4 scaling:on origin:(-1440,1437) degree:0" "id:4C405A05-8798-553B-3550-F93E7A7722BB res:1440x2560 color_depth:8 scaling:off origin:(3840,-363) degree:270" "id:18173D22-3EC6-E735-EEB4-B003BF681F30 res:1920x1200 color_depth:8 scaling:off origin:(960,-1200) degree:0"`

Also available via Homebrew brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer

Comment: thank you for both alternatives, I will try your tool, because I´m not sure about buying an App yet.

Comment: thanks for suggesting displayplacer.  Just wondering if this tool also sets the corresponding colour profile for each display?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question, SwitchResX doesn't seem to support the new MacOS natively. displayplacer is a great utility but doesn't seem to address display name changing concern.